# To make a comment?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> I thank them for the **comments they made** on my paper.

Am I right to think that "to make a comment" in such sentence as above is unidiomatic if not incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not right in thinking that it's wrong to say that. Comments are usually made. But don't confuse the act of making a comment, which can be done either physically with your mouth or by means of a computer using some form of electronic media, with the act of posting or leaving a comment on an Internet forum such as this one. Consider the following two examples:

> I'm still angry at her for the comments that she has been making about my mother.

In this example, I'm saying that I'm mad at her because of the negative statements she made with regard to my mother. The place where that happened could have equally been a physical one or an electronic one such as an Internet forum.

> I'm still angry at her for all the comments that she has been leaving to my questions.

In this example, however, I'm specifically talking about posting comments on an Internet forum.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, there is nothing unidiomatic about the clause **comments they made on my paper**. The clause is not introduced by **that**, but such an omission is grammatical and quite idiomatic. Because you give no indication as to why you think the clause may be incorrect, there is little to add about the clause over and above that it is fine.

It would, however, be an odd context where **I thank them** would be grammatical and idiomatic. In most contexts, what would be idiomatic would be **I thanked them**, **I have thanked them**, **I shall thank them**, **I must thank them**, or **I may thank them**.